# sums.append(map(int, row)) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a small program in Python 2.7 that read four numbers for each row from a text file and calculate sum for each row

file.txt :

```
1 2 4 5
5 5 5 12
3 3 89 21
1 0 5 6
```

My program:

```
def CalcSum(a,b,c,d):
    sum = a+b+c+d
    return sum

with open('file.txt', 'r') as i_file:
    reader = i_file.readline()
sums = []
for row in reader:
    sums.append(map(int, row))

for dt in sums:
    dt.append(CalcSum(dt[0], dt[1], dt[2], dt[3]))
print sums
i_file.close()
```

But when I rum my program I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/Erick/Desktop/testpy.py", line 10, in 
>       sums.append(map(int, row)) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

How can I fix this error ?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are probably lacking an `s`

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as i_file:
    reader = i_file.readlines()
```

Then with

```
sums.append(map(int, row))
```

you are applying `int` to each whole row in the file, not to each single number.

Further down in the code you have another error

```
for dt in sums:
    dt.append(CalcSum(dt[0], dt[1], dt[2], dt[3]))
```

is appending the sums to each list of numbers found.

finally

```
i_file.close()
```

closes the file unnecessarily, since it will be closed by the context manager created by the `with` statement (that is exactly the purpose of `with`)

So, to wrap it up nicely, here is the code fixed in full

```
def CalcSum(a,b,c,d):
    sum = a+b+c+d
    return sum

with open('file.txt', 'r') as i_file:
    reader = i_file.readlines()
sums = []
for row in reader:
    sums.append(map(int, row.split()))

final_sums = []
for dt in sums:
    final_sums.append(CalcSum(dt[0], dt[1], dt[2], dt[3]))
print final_sums
```

To make it more pythonic, let me suggest an alternative, more concise, version of the whole algorithm

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as i_file:
    final_sums = [sum(map(int,row.split())) for row in i_file]
```

If the file contains:

```
1 2 4 5
5 5 5 12
3 3 89 21
1 0 5 6
```

`final_sums` will hold

```
[12, 27, 116, 12]
```

Note: `readlines()` reads the whole contents of the file in memory. If the file is large it would be inconvenient.
Reading the contents one line at a time is more scalable.

Comment: @StefanPochmann thank you for pointing that out. I had read `readlines()` by default, tricked by the name `row` as well

Comment: oh, yes, you have two further errors down the line... I am going to edit my answer

Comment: the answer now contains the full code rewritten. I have just checked it, it works fine.